# Change of link button name based on radio value

Tags: jquery, radio-button, label

I have a table with a selection of input radio buttons. 2 of the radio input buttons have value ="P2" or "P1" and the rest values starting with S as you can see below

```
<input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(false);" type="radio" value="P2"/>
<input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(true);" type="radio" value="P1"/>


<input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(true);" type="radio" value="S111"/>
<input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(false);" type="radio" value="S112"/>
<input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(true);" type="radio" value="S131"/>
<input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(false);" type="radio" value="S132"/>
<input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(true);" type="radio" value="S121"/>
<input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(false);" type="radio" value="S122"/>
<a href='javascript: submitform("subsOptionform")' tabindex="14" class="right button blue">Subscribe</a>
```

I would like to have the label of the a link change from Subscribe to Buy credits when the 2 first radio buttons are selected.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You have **8** elements with the exact same ID. Good luck with getting anything to work. Also, you don't have a lick of jQuery in your code. I'd do some research on what jQuery *does* and then try and refactor your code to use it.

Comment: lol @Blender they do look like codes from the early 90's.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically the code cited above is just the source code copied as viewed on the browser. The page in question is developed in java and the  initial mark up with html5 and jQuery in place. As a matter of fact, the presentation of the 8 radio buttons on our table is achieved with jquery to present different prices depending on radio selection. I understand there is a specific id in place which does not help. Need to reconsider why is there.

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to change the IDs of your `input`s to unique values or nothing is guaranteed to work.

Next, try putting this in your `$(document).ready(function(){`:

```
$('.radio').change(function(){
    if($(this).attr('value') === 'P1' || $(this).attr('value') === 'P2'){
        $('.blue').text('Buy credits');
    }else{
        $('.blue').text('Subscribe');
    }
});
```

Comment: If he has more than instance of `$('.blue')` on that page, your script won't work as expected.

Comment: @mblase75 True, but he didn't give me much to work with (i.e., an ID would have been optimal.)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the reply. Can I ask why you used .blue? Can we create any other class? and how will the a link html look like?

Comment: @george I used `blue` because you did. The class you give a link does not necessarily determine how that link looks unless you specify it in your style sheet. For example, you could give a link `class='orange'` and it will still be blue in color.